# How can I clear a timer when a variable is set to true?

Tags: javascript

I'm just trying some JS animations, and I have animated a box that moves within borders, but I would like the animation to stop when the box hits one of the borders. This is one of the functions I use:

```
function AnimMoveRight() {
    var interval = setInterval("moveRight(10)", 40);
    if (hitRight == true) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

The `moveRight(10)` changes the box'position for 10 pixels to the right. `hitRight` is set true when the box hits the right border. Well, obviously, this code doesn't work, it just keeps on looping the `moveRight()` function. Now, my question is, how do I cancel the interval from within the `AnimMoveRight()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function AnimMoveRight() {
    var interval;
    function fnc(){
        if (hitRight == true) {
            window.clearInterval(interval);
        }
        else{
            moveRight(10);
        }
    }
    interval = setInterval(fnc, 40);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `interval` need to be defined outside of the function in order for it to be in scope when `fnc()` is called?

Answer (score 0):

If you check to see if it has hit the right before moving it will only call the animate function if it has yet to hit the right side, I chaged the function to setTimeout, I think this fits the task better.

```
function AnimMoveRight() {
    if (hitRight !== true) {
        moveRight(10);
        setTimeout(AnimMoveRight,40);
    }
}
```

Comment: But once the interval starts, when do you stop it? It'd continue forever once started.

Comment: ah you are correct, sorry i confused setTimeout with setInterval

Comment: I can't use setTimeout() for the animation, setTimeout() appears to just ignore the set delay when put in a loop...

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to get rid of setInterval altogether and just call setTimeout every iteration that doesn't result in a border hit:

```
function AnimMoveRight() {

    // Do stuff here

    if (!hitRight) {
        var nextCall = setTimeout("moveRight(10)", 40);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval` for greater control.
2. Use functions instead of strings when setting timers.
3. The common convention is to start function names with a lower case letter.
4. Directly check truthy/falsy expressions instead of comparing them to Booleans.

```
    function animMoveRight() {
        moveRight(10);

        if (!hitRight) {
            setTimeout(animMoveRight, 40);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, just move `clearInterval();` out of the `AnimMoveRight();` and do a global check for `hitRight`. And, if it's true, then clear the interval.

Or, define the `interval` variable in global scape, and on `AnimMoveRight();` set it. Then you could clear it within `AnimMoveRight();` too. Haven't tested neither, but I think both options would work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to cancel the interval from within `moveRight()`*.  The trick is letting  `moveRight()` know what the intervalId is.  Do you need to expose `moveRight()` as public?  If not, you could put it inside `AnimMoveRight`:

```
function AnimMoveRight() {
    function moveRight(n) {
        // do stuff
        if (hitRight) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }
    var interval = setInterval(function() { moveRight(10); }, 40);
}
```

Other options including passing `interval` as a parameter to `moveRight`:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() { moveRight(10, interval); }, 40);
```

Or do it right after the `moveRight()` call:

```
var interval = setInterval(function() {
    moveRight(10);
    if (hitRight) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 40);
```

***** This last one actually does cancel the interval from within `AnimMoveRight()`, as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Save the interval handle as a global, and check, within moveRight, if it needs to be canceled and if so cancel it there.

Better yet, use a closure so that the moveRight function can get to the interval handle without having to make it a global.

var interval = setInterval(function(){moveRight(10, interval);}, 40);

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function AnimMoveRight() {
    var interval;
    function animate() {
      var hitRight = moveRight(10);
      if (hitRight)
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    interval = setInterval(animate, 40);
}
```

Note that your moveRight shall return true|false.